# Kubernetes is there a way to give pod access to another pod from another namespace without using ClusterRoles

Tags: kubernetes-cluster, k8s-cluster-role

Kubernetes is there a way to give pod access to another pod from another namespace without using ClusterRoles. For Elastic on Kubernetes it is somehow working

Comment: You used the kubernetes tag which says "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."  Do you feel this question fits into this description?